# What can SQL CODE -104 (error) represent?

Tags: java, sql, db2, sqlcode, jcc

I am executing an SQL query via jcc to run a report. When I opened the error log file for the program and examined the SQL query, everything seems to be fine (There are no extra or missing brackets, commas, etc and the syntax is good) however when I execute I am getting this error:

[Report.execute()] DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=,;ATE IN (1,2,3,10,1)
;, DRIVER=4.12.55

When I researched about the SQLCODE I found out that it means there is an illegal symbol in the query. What can I look for to find this illegal symbol?

This is the query

[image]

Sorry for the tiny font but if you zoom 200% or so you can see the query better.

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense for you to post the query? Someone might be able to spot the symbol for you.

Comment: it is a bit long that's why I didn't post it! Well let me include it then

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have a comma (where you shouldn't) at the end of this line:

```
AND Tick.STATE IN (1,2,3,10,1),
```

The following line also has the same problem.

Comment: oh! sorry I'm still new to this! I thought that wasn't bad! Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had extra unnecessary ; at the end.

Answer (score 6):

Generally this SQL error code denotes that you have inserted some extra characters, such as **','** or  **'('** or **')'** or kind of. Checking the complete query in the trace will help for the people who write Sql queries inside a Java Program or such, as it took around 2 hours for me to figure out that I have a extra ')' in my query.

Comment: In my case it was a `;` at the end of query

Comment: In mine it was "\n" (I'm using jdbcTemplate)

Answer (score 0):

In My Case Problem was little different I wanted to joing two tables and then copy data from Table2 to Table1 respective column
My Query (DB2)
update  Table1  T1, Table2  T2
set  T1.DEST_COLMN= T2.SRC_COLMN
where  T1.ID= T2.ID

Correct Query 
update  Table1  T1
set  T1.DEST_COLMN = (select SRC_COLMN from  Table2  T2
                       where  T1.ID= T2.ID)

Answer (score 0):

I crashed this error because one of my query builder parameters was null and query was something like ".. OrderType = 'CM' and null".